# Pivot: Use column more than once each with its own filter

Tags: excel, pivot

On an excel pivot, I have a Date and Total column. I want to filter the date using 2 different dates, but have one column for each date total.

For example

```
Filter: Date
Rows: Name
Values: Sum of Total
```

Which brings

```
Filter 1/1/2019
Row Labels   Sum of Total
Bob          20
Mary         30
```

However, I want to use 2 different filters and 2 different columns to show:

```
Filter 1/1/2019 AND 1/2/2019
Row Labels   Sum of total-1   Sum of total-2
Bob          20               30
Mary         30               30
```

Where Sum of total-1 = 1/1/2019 and Sum of Total-2 = 1/2019. Is this possible with Excel Pivots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding Date in the Filters section, you can **add it in the columns section** and then filter the dates in the Column Labels:

[image: Column Labels]